# php Remove tag from html based on getAttribute

Tags: php

How can I limit which link tag is removed by specifying `$tag->getAttribute('rel') = "icon"`? I tried adding a simple if statement to the `$remove[] $tags as $tag;` line...code ran through, but the link with `rel="icon"` line was not at all removed.

So in this example the whole link tag should be removed from the html:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.ico" />


$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');

$remove = [];
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $remove[] = $tag;
}

foreach ($remove as $tag) {
    $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag); 
}
```

UPDATE Answer here:
@prodigitalson provided the following which initially did not work:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DOMXpath($dom);
$tags = $finder->query('//link[@rel="icon"]');

foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
$tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag); 
}
```

by adding the following line as the last line of the code...worked perfect.

```
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: why you not use str_replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get these all with an xpath:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DOMXpath($dom);
$tags = $finder->query('//link[@rel="icon"]');
$toRemove = array();

foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
  $toRemove[] = $tag;
}

// with array walk
array_walk(function($elem) { $elem->parentNode->removeChild($elem); }, $toRemove);

// with foreach
foreach ($toRemove as $tag) {
  $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
}
```

Comment: I tried your example...code ran through but the link was still there.

Comment: @KurtMarshman apparently when you iterate over a DOMNodeList you cant do in place removals - you need to kick the elements to an array for some reason. Answer updated. (Note: i didn't try this code out, but was going by this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#90292)

Comment: @prodigitalson....you were correct the first time. There was just 1 line missing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use easy way with function  str_replace:

```
<?php

//$html = file_get_contents($url);

$html = '<a rel="icon" href="#">link</a>';
$html = str_replace('rel="icon"', 'rel=""', $html);

echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: I am not seeing how str_replace will remove the whole link tag if rel="icon". So if the link rel="icon" remove this entirely.  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.ico" />